# Will my application work if i don't give handlerMapping in configuration file?

Tags: spring-mvc

This is my spring-servlet.xml file. I am new to spring MVC. Do we need to define bean for HelloWorld.Controller. If i don't define will it work?

```
 <bean id="viewResolver" class=" org.springframework.web.servlet.view. InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.vaannila.HelloWorldController" >
        <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
    </bean>

</beans>

If i don't give  this bean definition

 <bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.vaannila.HelloWorldController" >
        <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
    </bean>

MyApplication should work or not? I am new to spring MVC. In few tutorial this code is there and in few its not there. Please explain.
```

Comment: Why you don't try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to define the bean (way to create instance of class) for all the Controller/Service/Dao/Components class you want to use and set relevant properties.

I would recommend you to use Annotation based configuration (spring boot) as it eases all this process. You can find lot of tutorials on getting stated with spring boot. Here is one such good tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/